# How to not allow matching of the regex when i have a single quote preceded by a white space?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to not match when i have odd number of quotes if the starting of the quote is preceded by a white space.In case of nested quotation, only the outermost quote is considered. 
ex.

> please don "t turn on a "light". ->this should not match
>
> please don"t  turn on a "light". -> this should match "light"

I have done till matching of quotes

```
((?!^)(\s)".*?[\s]*"+)|(^".*?[\s]*"+)
```

sample test cases.

> turn on "Light A" and "Light B" -> matches light A and light B
>
> "Light A " was turned on  -> matches Light A
>
> She replied"as you say"   -> does not matches
>
> She replied "as you say"  -> matches "as u say"
>
> please don 't turn on a "light". ->this should not match
>
> please don "t turn on a 'light'. ->this should not match
>
> She replied "please turn on 'Light A'"  -> matches please turn on
>   light A
>
> please don "t turn on a "light". ->this should not match

Comment: `/(?!\b"\b)".*?(?!\b"\b)"/g` - https://regex101.com/r/eEX2dy/1

Comment: Sir, i didnt organise the test cases properly before. can we please tell me this ->
 please don "t turn on a "light". --> this should not match

Comment: `/(?<!\S)".*?"(?!\S)/g`? See https://regex101.com/r/bnHqjH/1. Are you extracting or replacing? Or removing the matches?

Comment: replacing sir !

Comment: it will be very helpful if u can explain it thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace a `"..."` substring in JS that has no whitespaces in front and after it you may use

```
.replace(/(\s|^)".*?"(?!\S)/g, '$1<REPLACEMENT_HERE>')
```

Or, to match any char including line break chars:

```
.replace(/(\s|^)"[^]*?"(?!\S)/g, '$1<REPLACEMENT_HERE>')
```

Or, if you only target the latest ECMAScript compatible JS environments, use

```
.replace(/(?<!\S)".*?"(?!\S)/g, '<REPLACEMENT_HERE>')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ok0aOY/1)

**Details**

- `(\s|^)` - Group 1: whitespace or start of string
- `"` - a `"`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `"` - a `"`
- `(?!\S)` - whitespace or end of string should follow the current position.

The `(?<!\S)` in the last example is a negative lookbehind that matches a location not immediately preceded with non-whitespace is not supported by the majority of browsers as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Javascript but have some info about regex. Following code is written in ipython.

1. Divided problem in parts:
2. Remove unwanted double quotes :  A double quote preceded and followed by alphanumeric. Replace unwanted double quote with blank.
       `re.sub('?<=[\w])(")(?[\w])',"",string,0,re.I)`
3. Find substring within double quotes.    `re.findall("""(?<!\w)"(.*?)"(?!\w)""",re.sub('?<=[\w])(")(?[\w])',"",string,0,re.I),"",text,0,re.I),re.I)`
4. By now, all substring should not contain double quote. If it has it means double quote is wrongly placed. For eg: "please don "t turn on a "light". Filter substring with double quote. Complete function:

```py
    def filter(text): 
     ...:     p1="""(?<!\w)"(.*?)"(?!\w)"""  
     ...:     p2="""(?<=[\w])(")(?=[\w])""" 
     ...:     matches=re.findall(p1,re.sub(p2,"",text,0,re.I),re.I)  
     ...:     for i in matches: 
     ...:         if re.search('"',i): 
     ...:            print("filtered",i) 
     ...:            matches.remove(i) 
     ...:         else: 
     ...:            print("kept",i) 
     ...:     return matches
```